# Create DateTime(long) in using JodaTime yields incorrect value

Tags: jodatime

I'm trying to use JodaTime (2.3) to store values returned from an API call in millis from epoch as a datetime string in SQLite3.

`new DateTime(Instant.now).toString()` or `Instant.now().toDateTime().toString()` both work as expected.

I'm having trouble with the [DateTime(long)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29) constructor, where I supply the long value.

For example:

`new DateTime(1388067172).toString()` gives `"1970-01-17T..."` (note, 17th not 1st so it is offsetting somewhat) whereas I expect it to be `"2013-12-26T..."`.

Answer (score 2):

My current unix-time is (was) `1388091226903`. I think you have to multiply the value you get with 1000, it seems to be given in seconds since 1st Jan 1970, but you want the time given in milliseconds since 1st of Jan 1970...

Comment: of course. I used [epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to validate, but checking again now, it takes both milliseconds and seconds! Thanks.